How to align all vertex on one plane at once
I need all the vertices to lie on one plane, but doing this one vertex at a time, by binding to the plane, takes a very long time. Is there a way to put all the vertices at once on one plane? The screenshot shows that several parts of the vertices are already lying on one plane, and the rest should lie on the same plane.


The plane seems to be at the height of the 3D Cursor. Set the Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor, select all vertices with shortcut A and then scale to 0 on the Z axis with the shortcuts S, Z, 0.

or select all, S, Z, 0, then open numbers panel and set mean Z to 0


Keep your vertex-line and the plane as two separate objects.

To vertex-line add a Shrinkwrap  modifier:
Wrench Button > Add Modifier > Deform > Shrinkwrap

Set plane as a target for Shrinkwrap

Apply Shrinkwrap if you need changes to be permanent (e.g. for further editing or before export)


